# no match for ‘operator-’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It has been a while since I changed my compiler, but when I did, my code that worked well earlier can no be compiled anymore - something I attribute to recent subtle changes in the C++ language standards (has not been following them too closely).

Ok. The code that used to work is:

```
VECTOR operator-(const VECTOR& v){  
    VECTOR tmp;
    tmp.x = x - v.x;
    tmp.y = y - v.y;
    tmp.z = z - v.z;
    return tmp;
}
```

Here, x, y, z are all public members of the class VECTOR

The class is used as:

```
VECTOR diff, A, B; 
diff = A - B;
```

When compiling it with g++6.2.0, I get the error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘const VECTOR’ and ‘const VECTOR’)
```

I followed various examples found online (including here) and implemented the operator overload via a friend function:

```
friend VECTOR operator-(VECTOR lhs, const VECTOR& rhs){  
    lhs.x -= rhs.x;
    lhs.y -= rhs.y;
    lhs.z -= rhs.z;
    return lhs;
}
```

This code compiles just well. I see the rationale for using a friend function, but I would like to know why the older (member-function) implementation doesn't work and how can I make it compiled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the member function needs to be const

```
VECTOR operator-(const VECTOR& v) const {  
                                  ^^^^^
```

Without this, the operator can't be applied to a `const` left-hand side argument.

Answer (score 3):

The member should certainly be `const`-qualified, as in

```
VECTOR operator-(const VECTOR& v) const {
                                  -----
```

The issue won't affect your particular example but it'll probably cause a problem somewhere, when you subtract `const VECTOR`'s.

---

Also, the `friend` signature is a little wonky. There was a brief period a few years ago when it was popular to recommend passing the LHS by value and returning it. However, copy elision doesn't work on parameter objects as it does on local variables. Copy elision is pretty important for operators like this since it reduces the number of objects that the program needs to initialize. So you might try this for performance:

```
friend VECTOR operator-(const VECTOR& lhs, const VECTOR& rhs){  
    VECTOR tmp;
    tmp.x = lhs.x - rhs.x;
    tmp.y = lhs.y - rhs.y;
    tmp.z = lhs.z - rhs.z;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Potatoswatter, for the hint on the performance. I'll give it a try